# Selenium Testing Table Scroll

Tags: selenium

I have 70 rows in a table.I could see 50 rows on UI
and remaining 20  rows I could see only after moving the scroll bar
down. Selenium is getting content only for the visible  50 rows.
I need to print all 70 rows information in console... could anyone help??

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample project. You can download it from the below link. You may get an annoying popup initially when you start running the script. Please close it manually. Apart from that you just have to change the chromedriver path in the script. Please let me know if you face any issue while executing this project.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ei9pKYca4923WKSk2R5suXZxqTJ0jbS-

Comment: Thank you... but I need to scroll table not window..and my problem cant able to understand how to iterate whole column by scrolling      String beforexpath="//div[@column='";
  String afterxpath="']";
  for(int i=0;i<=37;i++){
   
  List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(beforexpath+i+afterxpath));
              for (WebElement row : rows) {
           System.out.println(row.getText()); 
       if(i>9){
        
       }  
    }
       
  }.. this is not helping

Comment: That would be great if you will be able to share the piece of code with us. so that we can look into the behavior of that application and based on that we could help you in a better way my friend.

Comment: List<WebElement> elem = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@aria-colindex='1']"));
         for (Iterator<WebElement> iterator = elem.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
             WebElement webElement = (WebElement) iterator.next();
             JavascriptExecutor js1 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js1.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", webElement);
             String value = webElement.getText().substring(1);
             System.out.println(value);   
                           
         }

Comment: Totally there are 150rows..initially 50 rows i could see and i can get text of 50rows and but i can see remaining rows only when i scroll.. and i need to iterate whole 150rows.. This is my problem bhayya..how to use scroll here

Comment: Got that issue Bro :) I just want you to verify the behavior of the table. Could you please check this link once. https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/tables/scroll/ ( DataTable Vertical scroll )

Comment: Yes Bro.. Gone through

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check it out.